# NSURLConnection very slow start

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking

I recently upgraded one of my apps to make use of my js-c interop lib. By doing so i noticed that the main-server authentication, which also updates the js, via NSURLConnection takes a very long time until it handles the servers response.However The stange thing is that synchron NSURLConnections work fine. (see core.http inside my log) Any idea what is going on here?

```
2012-05-21 15:55:32.745 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::cl.start
2012-05-21 15:55:32.762 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::sv.invalidate push //[conn start];
2012-05-21 15:56:03.309 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::sv.invalidate auth //[conn didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge]
2012-05-21 15:56:04.092 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::sv.invalidate data //[conn didReceiveData]
2012-05-21 15:56:04.093 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::sv.invalidate pop //[conn connectionDidFinishLoading]

2012-05-21 15:56:04.329 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.init->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.348 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.init->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:04.594 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.load->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.608 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.load->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:04.624 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.settings->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.635 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.settings->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.639 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.settings->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:04.645 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.settings->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:04.667 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::db.testentity.meta.select->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.681 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::db.testentity.meta.select->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:04.687 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::db.testentity.data.select->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.714 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.http.get->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.755 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::db.testentity.data.select->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:04.812 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.http.post->push
2012-05-21 15:56:04.840 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.http.post->push
2012-05-21 15:56:05.734 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.http.get->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:05.756 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::db.testentity.meta.make->push
2012-05-21 15:56:05.762 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::db.testentity.meta.make->pop
2012-05-21 15:56:05.868 myApplication[6327:707] libcrpt::core.http.post->pop
```

Comment: Are you able to watch the network traffic, perhaps at the router? Maybe it's deleayed by DNS lookups?

Comment: Nope but i managed to go down to 4 secs delay by changing: [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:connHandler startImmediately:NO]  to [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:connHandler]  ... still way slower than synchronous requests but at least it can be used.